# Taylor theorem with general remainder formula

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, taylor-expansion

I came across Taylor theorem as following:

Let the function $f(x)$ have $n+1$ derivatives in $(a- \delta , a+\delta )$ of the point $a$ and $p>0$.Then for every $x \in (a- \delta , a+\delta )$ there exist $c \in (a,x)$ so that:

$$\begin{align}f(x) =  &\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(x-a)^k}{k!}f^{(k)}(a) \\&+ \left(\frac{x-a}{x-c}\right)^p\frac{(x-c)^{n+1}}{n!p}f^{(n+1)}(c)  \end{align}  $$

I am curious , what is the proof of this theorem?

if you plug in for example $p=n+1$ you get the Lagrange remainder.But I didn't quite find anywhere a proof with $p$ where the remainder is expressed like that. Can someone share full proof of this theorem or link where this is proved ?

Comment: Always worth telling us **where** you can across it.

Comment: Never in my 50+ years as a mathematician have I encountered this. Where did you find it?

Comment: So I was checking some documents with Taylor series and I came across this , it is not from a book and I don't know the author.

Comment: I have translated the theorem from the paper, I hope that the translation is not wrong but for the equation $f(x) =....$ , I am certain it is written like that.

Comment: @Danilo: OK, I've given you a proof. Can you enlighten me why this is remotely interesting? The document you stumbled upon has an interesting application of it?

Comment: There was a question how would you derive the Lagrange formula and of course first this theorem has to be proved then to plug in p=n+1 and that completes what they want.

Comment: That's certainly not interesting. Arcane mathematics for the sake of more arcane mathematics.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have a proof for you. It's based on Lagrange's approach to proving the "usual" Lagrange form of the remainder formula. (See, for example, problem 19 in Chapter 20 of Spivak's *Calculus*, 4th edition.) His trick is to let the point $a$ vary and consider
$$f(x) = P_{n,t}(x) + R_{n,t}(x).$$
Here $P_{n,t}(x) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \dfrac{f^{(k)}(t)}{k!}(x-t)^k$ and $R_{n,t}$ is the remainder. For ease of notation, since we will fix $n$ and $x$, let's write $R(t)=R_{n,t}(x)$.

Note that $R(x)-R(a)=0-R_{n,a}(x) = -(f(x)-P_{n,a}(x))$. Let $g(t)=(x-t)^p$. Then $g(x)-g(a) = -(x-a)^p$.  It looks very promising to apply the Cauchy Mean Value Theorem:
$$\frac{R(x)-R(a)}{g(x)-g(a)} = \frac{f(x)-P_{n,a}(x)}{(x-a)^p} = \frac{R'(c)}{g'(c)}.$$
Since $g'(c)=-p(x-c)^{p-1}$, so things are starting to look good. The critical step will be to compute $R'(t)$.

We have $R(t) = f(x) - \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \dfrac{f^{(k)}(t)}{k!}(x-t)^k$, so
\begin{align*}
R'(t) &= -\sum_{k=0}^n \left(\frac{f^{(k+1)}(t)}{k!}(x-t)^k -\frac{f^{(k)}(t)}{(k-1)!}(x-t)^{k-1}\right) \\
&= -\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f^{(k+1)}(t)}{k!}(x-t)^k + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{f^{(k+1}(t)}{k!}(x-t)^k \\
&= -\frac{f^{(n+1)}(t)}{k!}(x-t)^n.
\end{align*}

And now it all falls in place:
\begin{align*}
\frac{f(x)-P_{n,a}(x)}{(x-a)^p} &= \frac{R'(c)}{g'(c)}\\
&=\frac{-\frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{k!}(x-c)^n}{-p(x-c)^{p-1}} \\ &= \frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{k!p} (x-c)^{n+1-p},
\end{align*}
from which we get
\begin{align*}
f(x)-P_{n,a}(x) &= \frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{k!p} (x-c)^{n+1-p} (x-a)^p \\ &= \left(\frac{x-a}{x-c}\right)^p \frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{k!p} (x-c)^{n+1},
\end{align*}
as desired.

Answer (score 6):

**Corollary of the Mean Value Theorem**

Assume that $g(x)\gt0$ for $a\lt x\lt b$ and define
$$
h(x)=\int_a^xf(t)g(t)\,\mathrm{d}t
$$
and
$$
k(x)=\int_a^xg(t)\,\mathrm{d}t
$$
Then there is a $c$ between $a$ and $b$ so that
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{\int_a^bf(t)g(t)\,\mathrm{d}t}{\int_a^bg(t)\,\mathrm{d}t}
=\frac{h(b)-h(a)}{k(b)-k(a)}=\frac{h'(c)}{k'(c)}=\frac{f(c)g(c)}{g(c)}=f(c)}
$$

---

The Taylor's Formula with the Integral form of the Remainder is
$$
f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(x-a)^k}{k!}f^{(k)}(a)+\int_a^x\frac{(x-t)^n}{n!}f^{(n+1)}(t)\,\mathrm{d}t
$$
The corollary above then says,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_a^x\frac{(x-t)^n}{n!}f^{(n+1)}(t)\,\mathrm{d}t
&=\int_a^x\frac{(x-t)^{p-1}\color{#C00}{(x-t)^{n-p+1}}}{\color{#C00}{n!}}\color{#C00}{f^{(n+1)}(t)}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\color{#C00}{\frac{(x-c)^{n-p+1}f^{n+1}(c)}{n!}}\int_a^x(x-t)^{p-1}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac{(x-c)^{n-p+1}f^{n+1}(c)}{n!}\frac{(x-a)^p}p\\
&=\left(\frac{x-a}{x-c}\right)^p\frac{(x-c)^{n+1}}{n!p}f^{(n+1)}(c)
\end{align}
$$